# Trying to remove buttons on click, but they keep coming back (JavaScript, HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I'm having this problem with buttons that I don't know how to solve. I have a table, and each row has a "Pack" action button. When it's clicked, the button is removed so that the user can't accidentally click it again and 'pack' the same item twice.

It has been working well so far, but I just noticed that when you click to the next page of the table (when it has more than 15 or so rows) and go back to the first page again, any buttons you clicked on that first page (and removed) are back.

No matter what pages you move to, I need my table to "remember" which rows' action buttons were clicked/removed. I have no idea how to do this, though.

**Here is my code that removes the action  button when you click:**

```
// Pack action button
$(document).on('click', ".box-electrode", function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    var sn = $(this).data('sn');
    addElectrodeToBox(id, sn);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The table itself is created using DataTables.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**

Here is some code I've come up with based on the answer below, but it's not working. There are no errors in the JS console, it just doesn't seem to do anything.

```
$(document).on('page.dt', function () {
    var $allSerialNumbers = $('.box-electrode');

    $('#electrodes li').each(function (i, li) {
        var $id = $(li).data('id');
        for(var index = 0; index < $allSerialNumbers.length; index++){
            if($id == $allSerialNumbers.eq(index).attr('data-id')){
                $('.box-electrode').eq(index).remove();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

`$allSerialNumbers` represents all the action buttons, and `$('#electrodes')` is the list I'm comparing to.

I think part of the problem (other than my clumsy JS skills) might be that DataTables' Page Change Event `page.dt` only seems to affect the page that is being changed, rather than the page being changed *to*. For example, when I'm on the 2nd page of my table and click back to the first page, my JS code is acting on the 2nd page instead of the 1st (which is what I need).

Comment: this is because the HTML reloads when you change page. One solution would be to use localstorage for storing the clicked buttons

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a JavaScript empty array;
2. DataTables library has page changing event;
3. When user presses the button - get button's value, store it in the array and remove the button;
4. When user changes the page - page's change event will be fired -> cleaning function will be executed, which will read the array, search needed buttons by value and remove them if exist.

Comment: Can you see the code I added to the bottom of my question? I tried to create some javascript based on what you said about the Page Change Event but it's not working.

Comment: Where you buttons are located? When I set them inside the last column they do not appear again after switching page:

        `<tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td><button value="b5">e</button></td>
        </tr>`

Comment: They are in the first column. I'm using Underscore.js templating to create a button on each row of the table.